# Start glassfish server on different port

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have created a new domain `ac` and defined a different port in `domain.xml` i.e. `11305`. But when I try to start the domain it gives me following exception:

> com.sun.enterprise.universal.xml.MiniXmlParserException: "Xml Parser Error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[253,34]
>
> Message: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "port".

Here is the command:

```
./asadmin start-domain ac
```

Here is the part of the domain.xml file

```
<network-listeners>

          <network-listener port=“11305” protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>

          <network-listener port="33389" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>

          <network-listener port="33356" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>

        </network-listeners>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The xml config got malformed. Check if the port value is quoted and check if your quote is the right symbol (try copying quotes from other places in the xml)

Update: First and second quotes are non-standard in your excerpt of the domain.xml file, 3rd line. Compare the quotes around `11305` and the quotes around `http-listener-1`. They are different. The quotes around `http-listener-1` are proper and you should use those.

Comment: I double checked it ... its fine

Comment: Can you paste an excerpt of the config with surroundings of that part you changed?

Comment: @Varis is correct. The problem is with your XML, and the error message is even telling you the exact character that is wrong. Go to line 253 and the 34th character in that line will be wrong. Check if you've added a space where there shouldn't be one, e.g just after the equals sign like this: `port= "11305"`

Comment: I have added the part where I changed. Kindly check

Comment: The quotes in "...<network-listener port=“11305” pro..." are non-standard quotes. Use standard english quotes. Try copying the quote symbols from other places or use a US english keyboard layout when typing them.